# Round up to the nearest tenth?

Tags: ruby, math, rounding

I need to round up to the nearest tenth. What I need is `ceil` but with precision to the first decimal place.

Examples:

```
10.38 would be 10.4
10.31 would be 10.4
10.4 would be 10.4
```

So if it is any amount past a full tenth, it should be rounded up.

I'm running Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works in general:

```
ceil(number*10)/10
```

So in Ruby it should be like:

```
(number*10).ceil/10.0
```

Comment: This is what I do, but I wish there was a native way to do this, like roundup(1) or something.

Comment: How would you accomplish this for two decimal places (like for money?) EDIT: Derp. (3.191*100).ceil/100.0 was giving me 3.2. Thats correct, 3.20. Just wasn't showing the extra 0.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby's round method can consume precisions:

```
10.38.round(1) # => 10.4
```

In this case 1 gets you rounding to the nearest tenth.

Comment: I'd recommend this answer in 1.9.3 and above ( http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round ).  Ruby 1.8.7 and earlier only rounded to integer values ( http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Float.html#method-i-round ).

Comment: 10.31.round(1) => 10.3 and not 10.4, as the OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ActiveSupport available, it adds a round method:

```
3.14.round(1) # => 3.1
3.14159.round(3) # => 3.142
```

The source is as follows:

```
def round_with_precision(precision = nil)
  precision.nil? ? round_without_precision : (self * (10 ** precision)).round / (10 ** precision).to_f
end
```

Comment: This rounds to the NEAREST tenth, not UP to the nearest tenth as the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

To round up to the nearest tenth in Ruby you could do

`(number/10.0).ceil*10`

`(12345/10.0).ceil*10`  # => 12350

Answer (score 0):

```
(10.33  + 0.05).round(1) # => 10.4
```

This always rounds up like **ceil**, is concise, supports precision, and without the goofy /10 *10.0 thing.

Eg. round up to nearest hundredth:

```
(10.333  + 0.005).round(2) # => 10.34
```

To nearest thousandth:

```
(10.3333  + 0.0005).round(3) # => 10.334
```

etc.