# Rails Rounding float with different options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where user enters a decimal value and a drop down with four options: `Dollar (.00)`, `Quarter (.00, .25, .50, .75)`,  `Dime (.10, .20, .30 .. .90)` and `Penny (.01, .02, .03 ... .99)`. Also there is an option to select either round `UP` or `DOWN`.

These options are used to round the value entered by the user. I monkey patched the `Float` class and added `round_to_quarter` that works fine:

```
class Float
  def round_to_quarter
    (self * 4).round / 4.0
  end

  def round_to_dime
    #TODO
  end

  def round_to_penny
    #TODO
  end

  def round_to_dollar
    #TODO
  end  
end

9.22.round_to_quarter #=> 9.25
```

How do I round the value for Dime(.10, .20, .30 .. .90) and Penny (.01, .02, .03 ... .99) options and round up and down?

The Ruby version is 2.2.3

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233218/round-up-to-the-nearest-tenth), at least with `to_dime`

Comment: The `to_dime` would be `(self * 10).round / 10.0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a generic way to do it for any precision:

```
class Float
  def round_currency(precision: 1, direction: :none)
    round_method = case direction
      when :none then :round
      when :up   then :ceil
      when :down then :floor
    end

    integer_value = (self * 100).round
    ((integer_value / precision.to_f).send(round_method) * precision / 100.0)
  end
end


# USAGE
9.37.round_currency(direction: :none, precision: 10)
# => 9.4

9.37.round_currency(direction: :up, precision: 25)
# => 9.5

9.37.round_currency(direction: :none)
# => 9.37

# Precision is defined in pennies: 10 dime, 25 quarter, 100 dollar. 1 penny is default
```

This code converts the float into an integer first to ensure accuracy. Be wary using `ceil` and `floor` with floating number arithmetic - due to accuracy errors you could get odd results e.g. `9.37 * 100 = 936.9999999999999`. If you `floor` the result, you'll end up rounding to 9.36

Comment: The `precision` would get 4 for Quarter, 10 for Dime and 100 for penny ?

Comment: Default `1` is no rounding (penny). Use `10` for dime, `25` for quarter and `100` for dollar

Comment: And for dollar (.00) ?

Comment: @Arif: you'll want to use `100`. I've updated the snippet to clarify this

Comment: Maybe use `BigDecimal` instead to avoid the floating point precision issues. This could be added easily  `integer_value = (BigDecimal.new(self) * 100).round`

Answer (score 1):

One more way to handle the situation:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
class Rounder
  DENOMS = {penny: 0.01, nickel: 0.05, dime: 0.1, quarter: 0.25, half_dollar: 0.5, dollar: 1.0}
  DENOMS.each do |denom,val|
    define_method("round_to_#{denom}") do |direction: :nearest|
        self.send(direction, self.send(:step_def, val))
    end     
  end
  def initialize(v)
    @v = BigDecimal(v.to_s)
    @enum_range = (@v.floor..@v.floor + 1)
  end

  def round_to(denom,direction: :nearest)
    check_denom(denom)
    if denom.is_a?(Numeric)
      self.send(direction, self.send(:step_def, denom))
    else
      self.public_send("round_to_#{denom}",direction: direction) 
    end    
  end


  private 
    def down(enum)
        enum.reverse_each.detect {|f| f <= @v }
    end
    def up(enum) 
        enum.detect {|f| f >= @v }
    end
    def nearest(enum)
      [up(enum),down(enum)].min_by {|n| (n - @v).abs}
    end
    def step_def(val)
      @enum_range.step(val)
    end  
    def check_denom(denom)
      if denom.is_a?(Numeric)
        raise ArgumentError, "Numeric denom must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1" if (denom > 1 || denom <= 0)
      elsif denom.respond_to?(:to_sym)
        raise ArgumentError, "expecting one of #{DENOMS.keys} got :#{denom.to_sym}" unless DENOMS.keys.include?(denom.to_sym)
      else
        raise ArgumentError,"expected Numeric, Symbol or String got #{denom.class}"
      end
    end    
end
```

This allows flexible implementation for predefined denominations as well as rounding to any precision desired. Obviously this could be optimized a bit for longer precision's by scaling down the `@enum_range`.

You could patch this in to `Numeric` to allow direct access:

```
class Numeric
  def round_to(denom,direction: :nearest)
    Rounder.new(self).round_to(denom,direction: direction)
  end
end
```

Then usage as such

```
r = Rounder.new(9.22)
r.round_to_quarter
#=> 9.25
r.round_to_dime(direction: :up)
#=> 9.3
r.round_to(:nickel)
#=> 9.2
r.round_to(0.45, direction: :up)
#=> 9.45
r.round_to({})
#=> ArgumentError: expected Numeric, Symbol or String got Hash
r.round_to(:pound)
#=> ArgumentError: expecting one of [:penny, :nickel, :dime, :quarter,
#     :half_dollar, :dollar] got :pound
77.43.round_to(:quarter)
#=> 77.5
Rounder.new("123.0000001").round_to_half_dollar(direction: :up)
#=> 123.5
#Obviously a Fixnum is already precise but it does still work 
[:down,:up].each do |dir|
  puts "#{dir} => #{12.round_to(:quarter, direction: dir)}"
end
# down => 12.0
# up => 12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following overrides...

Ceil goes with UP and Floor goes with DOWN

```
class Float
  def ceil_to_quarter
    (self * 4).ceil / 4.0
  end

  def floor_to_quarter
    (self * 4).floor / 4.0
  end

  def ceil_to_dime
    (self * 10).ceil / 10.0
  end

  def floor_to_dime
    (self * 10).floor / 10.0
  end

  def ceil_to_penny
    (self * 10).ceil / 10.0
  end 

  def floor_to_penny
    (self * 100).floor / 100.0
  end 
end
```

Comment: And dollar (.00) ?

Answer (score 0):

Round to penny should work fine just like quarters

```
def round_to_penny
  ((self * 100).round/100.0)
end
```

Round to dime would however reduce to 1 decimal place since you are rounding to 1 decimal place. 
You could change it to 2 decimal places when displaying the value.

```
def round_to_dime
  ((self * 10).round/10.0)
end
```

You could use '%.2f' however:

```
'%.2f' % 9.25.round_to_dime => "9.30"
```